# symfony: add EntityManager to an Entity Class

Tags: service, doctrine, symfony

I have an Entity called "Vote" and I need to use doctrine in this class to exec some operations to integrate values from this class into EasyAdmin bundle show list.

I have this in my services.yml:

```
app.user:
        class: AppBundle\Entity\Vote
        calls:
                 - ['setMe', ["doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]]
```

and this in my Class:

```
public function setMe($entityManager) {
    $this->em = $entityManager;
}
```

but setMe() is never called (I'm using xdebug).

So, I have tried with :

```
app.user:
    class: AppBundle\Entity\Vote
    calls:
             - ['setMe', ["doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]]
    arguments:    ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
```

and

```
public function __construct(\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $em){
        $this -> date = new \DateTime();
        $this -> em = $em;
    }
```

but with the same result: $this->em is not set.

Where is my mistake ?

Comment: Your first mistake is thinking that configuring the Symfony container will magically cause the injection to occur.  The container will only work if you pull the entity from the container, something which is not going to happen in Doctrine 2.  Your second mistake is trying to inject the entity manager in the first place.  Doctrine 2 entities are not active record entities.  Move the functionality to a service class or switch to an active record library.

Answer (score 0):

You (almost) never should needs entity manager in entity and entity shouldn't be a service, i think.

But if you realy need it, you should use [service container](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#creating-configuring-services-in-the-container). If you call `$this->get('app.user');` in your controller, it should returns `Vote` entity. Or use controller injection.